# Dividing a list of matrices by different sets of matrices

Tags: r, matrix, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a list of matrices, and I have a few different matrix that I would like to divide the elements in the list of matrices by. I would like to go down the list by sets of threes and calculate the difference between the minimum `jDate` for in `int1` and `int2`, as shown below for `n1`, `n2`,and `n3`. I would then like to divide the matrix created from these values `m1` from one of the matrix in the list. I would then move down to the next set of three elements in the list for `int1` and `int2` and calculate the differences between those, and repeat the same process as the first set of three. How would I go about doing this?

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("26-12-2010"), dmy("20-12-2013"), by = "days"), 500)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df$jDate <- julian(as.Date(df$date), origin = as.Date('1970-01-01'))
df$Month <- month(df$date)

t1 <- c(100,150,200)
t2 <- c(200,250,350)
t3 <- c(300,350, 400)
mat <- cbind(t1,t2, t3)

t1 <- c(150,150,200)
t2 <- c(250,250,350)
t3 <- c(350,350, 400)
mat2 <- cbind(t1,t2, t3)

l1 <- list(mat, mat2)

int1 <- df %>%
  # arrange(ID) %>%   # skipped for readability of result
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, new) %>%
  filter(Month == "3") %>% 
  group_split()

int2 <- df %>%
  # arrange(ID) %>%   # skipped for readability of result
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, new) %>%
  filter(Month == "2") %>% 
  group_split()

n1 <- c(((min(int1[[1]]$jDate))- min(int2[[1]]$jDate)),
        ((min(int1[[1]]$jDate))- min(int2[[2]]$jDate)),
        ((min(int1[[1]]$jDate))- min(int2[[3]]$jDate)))

n2 <- c(((min(int1[[2]]$jDate))- min(int2[[1]]$jDate)),
        ((min(int1[[2]]$jDate))- min(int2[[2]]$jDate)),
        ((min(int1[[2]]$jDate))- min(int2[[3]]$jDate)))

n3 <-  c(((min(int1[[3]]$jDate))- min(int2[[1]]$jDate)),
         ((min(int1[[3]]$jDate))- min(int2[[2]]$jDate)),
         ((min(int1[[3]]$jDate))- min(int2[[3]]$jDate)))
m1 <- cbind(n1,n2,n3)


l1[[1]]/m1
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how to make `l1` with a length of 10 elements without having a bunch of repetitive code for the example. Even if you have a suggestion for dividing the first element by a matrix and the second element by a different matrix, it would still provide some clarity for how I can go about getting the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split`the `list` by a grouping index, create a function ('f1') based on the OP's creation of `matrix` from those 3 element `list`s, use `map2` from `purrr` to loop over the `split` `list`s,

```
library(purrr)
g1 <- as.integer(gl(length(int1), 3, length(int1)))
f1 <- function(.int1 ,.int2) {

   n1 <- c(((min(.int1[[1]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[1]]$jDate)),
        ((min(.int1[[1]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[2]]$jDate)),
        ((min(.int1[[1]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[3]]$jDate)))

n2 <- c(((min(.int1[[2]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[1]]$jDate)),
        ((min(.int1[[2]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[2]]$jDate)),
        ((min(.int1[[2]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[3]]$jDate)))

n3 <-  c(((min(.int1[[3]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[1]]$jDate)),
         ((min(.int1[[3]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[2]]$jDate)),
         ((min(.int1[[3]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[3]]$jDate)))
out <- cbind(n1,n2,n3)
out}
```

apply the function, then divide the 'l1' list elements with the corresponding elements of 'lstMat' (Here the reproducible example showed two list elements in 'l1', so we subset the 'lstMat' (`[1:2]`) to do the division

```
lstMat <- map2(split(int1, g1), split(int2, g1), ~  f1(.x, .y))
map2(l1, lstMat[1:2], `/`)
[[1]]
     t1        t2        t3
[1,]  4  5.714286  6.666667
[2,] 10 10.000000 10.000000
[3,] 40 23.333333 16.000000

[[2]]
       t1        t2       t3
[1,]  5.0  6.250000  7.00000
[2,]  7.5  8.333333  8.75000
[3,] 20.0 17.500000 13.33333
```

-checking with OP's output for first the first case

```
l1[[1]]/m1
     t1        t2        t3
[1,]  4  5.714286  6.666667
[2,] 10 10.000000 10.000000
[3,] 40 23.333333 16.000000
```

---

The OP's function wrapped 'f1' can be modified by simplifying with `outer`

```
f2 <- function(.int1, .int2) {
   t(outer(seq_along(.int1), seq_along(.int2), 
      FUN = Vectorize(function(i, j)  min(.int1[[i]]$jDate) - 
           min(.int2[[j]]$jDate))))
}
```

Now, try the same code to create 'lstMat'

```
lstMat <- map2(split(int1, g1), split(int2, g1), f2)
 map2(l1, lstMat[1:2], `/`)
[[1]]
     t1        t2        t3
[1,]  4  5.714286  6.666667
[2,] 10 10.000000 10.000000
[3,] 40 23.333333 16.000000

[[2]]
       t1        t2       t3
[1,]  5.0  6.250000  7.00000
[2,]  7.5  8.333333  8.75000
[3,] 20.0 17.500000 13.33333
```

Comment: How would I modify this code if the matrices in `l1` had different dimensions? For example, if instead of a 2x3 matrix it had a 2x2 matrix or a 2x3 matrix.

Comment: @JohnHuang I think the element of 'l1' have the same dimension as the 'm1' matrix. Can you post as a new question. thanks

Comment: Sorry wrong link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70673876/dividing-matrices-with-unequal-dimensions-in-r?noredirect=1#comment124939944_70673876

Comment: @JohnHuang I posted a solution at that link.  Is that what you wanted?