# Dividing matrices with unequal dimensions in r

Tags: r, list, matrix, dplyr, purrr

I have a data set that I had filtered into a single month. I also have a list of matrices (`l1`) that is the same length as the list of data frames (`int1`). The matrices in the list have different dimensions (e.g.,3x3, 2x2).

Setting the data and list:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("26-12-2010"), dmy("13-07-2011"), by = "days"), 200)
ID <- rep(c("A","B"), 100)
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df$jDate <- julian(as.Date(df$date), origin = as.Date('1970-01-01'))
df$Month <- month(df$date)

# First 10-day interval for `A`
t1 <- c(100,150,200)
# Second 10-day interval for `A`
t2 <- c(200,250,350)
# Third 10-day interval for `A`
t3 <- c(300,350, 400)
mat <- cbind(t1,t2, t3)

# First 10-day interval for `B`
t1 <- c(150,150)
# Second 10-day interval for `B`
t2 <- c(250,250)
mat2 <- cbind(t1,t2)

l1 <- list(mat, mat2)

int1 <- df %>%
  # arrange(ID) %>%   # skipped for readability of result
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, new) %>%
  filter(Month == "3") %>% 
  group_split()
```

The code below attempts to divide `lstMat` from `l1`. The problem that I am running into is that matrices in `lstMat` do not have the same dimensions as the matrices in `l1`. Due this discrepency, when I try and divide one from the other I receive the error message: `Error in .x/.y : non-conformable arrays`

```
g1 <- as.integer(gl(length(int1), 3, length(int1)))

f2 <- function(.int1, .int2) {
  t(outer(seq_along(.int1), seq_along(.int2), 
          FUN = Vectorize(function(i, j)  min(.int1[[i]]$jDate) - 
                            min(.int2[[j]]$jDate))))
}
lstMat <- map2(split(int1, g1), split(int1, g1), f2)
map2(l1, lstMat[1:2], `/`)
```

Any thoughts on how I can modify this code to allow for differences in matrices with the list?

Problem:
I have matrices with different dimensions that I have been trying to divide. Let say I run a custom function and end with `l1`. The matrices in `l1` correspond to the 10-day intervals in `int1`, but we didn't get an output for the third 10-day interval for `ID` `B` hence a 2x2 matrix.

Rules:
In this case, I would like to remove the third column from `lstMat[[2]]` because that is the one missing from `l1[[2]]`. This wouldn't always be the case, for example if the second 10-day interval was missing from `l1[[2]]`, then I would want to remove the second column in `lsMat[[2]]`.

I would like to link `lstMat` and `l1` through the use of `int1` based on the specific intervals that end up getting removed from `lstMat`.

I hope I didn't make this more confusing. I apologize if I did.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In the example above, using the second element of each list, you want to divide a 2x2 matrix by a 3x3 matrix.  What exactly do you want R to do for you?  That is, what is the expected output for `l1[[2]]/lstMat[[2]]`?

Comment: The expected output for `l1[[2]]/lstMat[[2]]` is to be a 2z2 matrix. I think I would like one of the columns to be removed to match the dimensions of `l1[[2]]`. Essentially, I would like the dimensions of the matrices in the final output to match those of `l1`.

Comment: You could do that, but which column(s) would you remove?  If `l1[[j]]` is nxn and `lstMat[[j]]` is mxm, do you take the first n rows and columns of `lstMat[[j]]` or that last n rows and columns or something else?  For this to work, you'd have to have a rule that you could apply across all cases.

Comment: I think it would depend on what is missing from `int1`. In this example `int1` is broken down into 3 10-day intervals. The columns/rows in the matrix corresponds to a single interval in `int1`. The column that gets removed would depend on the interval that would potentially be missing from `int1`.

Comment: If you can describe the rule you would use in your question, we could likely help you figure out how to make it work in R.

Comment: I've added the rules to the question, I hope I didn't make it increasingly more difficult to understand.

Comment: @JohnHuang the 'g1' is fixed replication.  YOu may need to change the replication based on the lstMat dimensions. i.e. `g1 <- rep(c(1, 2, 3), c(3, 2, 1)); lstMat <- map2(split(int1, g1), split(int1, g1), f2);map2(l1, lstMat[1:2], `/`)` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the 'g1' needs to be dynamic based on the number of rows/dimensions of each of the elements in 'lstMat'.  This can be done with `rep`

```
library(purrr)
g1 <- rep(seq_along(lstMat), sapply(lstMat, nrow))
lstMat <- map2(split(int1, g1), split(int1, g1), f2)
map2(l1, lstMat[1:2], `/`)
[[1]]
      t1  t2  t3
[1,] Inf  20  15
[2,] -15 Inf  35
[3,] -10 -35 Inf

[[2]]
      t1  t2
[1,] Inf  25
[2,] -15 Inf
```

Some values are `Inf` only because we have some values in the 'lstMat' as '0'

```
lstMat[1:2]
$`1`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0   10   20
[2,]  -10    0   10
[3,]  -20  -10    0

$`2`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0   10
[2,]  -10    0
```

Thus any value divided by 0 returns `Inf`

Comment: @JohnHuang `lstMat` and `lsMat` are different.  Did you define without `t`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I meant `lstMat` where I wrote `lsMat`.

Comment: @JohnHuang Did you changed the example

Comment: When I try to run `g1` it gives me the error that `lstMat` is missing. Is there a way to get around that, so that I could get to the next instance where I define `lstMat`?

Comment: @JohnHuang this was working when I posted the solution, but now i think you may have changed the example because `lstMat` is not defined.  Probably, `g1 <- rep(seq_along(l1), sapply(l1, nrow))` but the `int1` is kind of changing

Comment: I didn't change the example. When replacing your `g1` code with the one in the example, it gives the error that `lstMat` is missing. I think its due to the `lstMat` coming after the `g1`. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: @JohnHuang if i check the number of rows in `int1` `sapply(int1, nrow)#
[1] 5 5 5 5 5 6`, the last one is 6 instead of 5.  I guess this was not the case earlier

Comment: @JohnHuang As I mentioned before in the comments, the the length of `int1` is 6, which is not aligning with the `l1`.  Perhaps you want to select only until it reaches the length i.e. `g1 <- rep(seq_along(l1), sapply(l1, nrow));
lstMat <- map2(split(int1[seq_len(length(g1))], g1), split(int1[seq_len(length(g1))], g1), f2);
map2(l1, lstMat[1:2], `/`)
[[1]]
      t1  t2  t3
[1,] Inf  20  15
[2,] -15 Inf  35
[3,] -10 -35 Inf

[[2]]
      t1  t2
[1,] Inf  25
[2,] -15 Inf`